# Please add “homework” to the one-click comment flagging list

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags, comment-flags, homework

Comments about homework [cause a lot of friction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130558/can-we-cut-back-on-the-is-this-homework-berating). In the interest of making it easier to cut off the comment wars in the bud, please add `homework` to the list of words that make a comment be deletable by a single flag.

[image: beware of the unicorn]

Now that [the homework tag is being phased out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100), I'm flagging comments like “add the homework tag” as obsolete as I find them. Making this one-click would lighten the load for moderators.

<sub>We're about 1/4 of the way through the tag cleanup. This would still help.</sub>

Comment: +1 for the killer unicorn sign.

Comment: @PopularDemand Yup. As far as I know the list has never been made public.

Comment: If this Meta post is your homework, can you show what you've tried? ;)

Comment: @jonsca The unicorn picture is indeed homework, but not mine. I can't show you what I've tried because there's no public record of my comment flags.

Comment: @Gilles Well this can't just be a "gimme teh changez" situation, then.    Okay, I'll stop now.

Comment: @jonsca You said homework! *flags*

Comment: @John: *[your comment suddenly disappears]*

Comment: @RobertHarvey ♦cheater.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If you're not part of the solution, you're part of the problem, man...

Comment: One disgruntled guy complaining about a post from years ago counts as "a lot of friction"? Where's the evidence that this is needed?

Comment: These comments annoy me, and Gilles apparently. Isn't that evidence enough? They cause us a lot of friction.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: No, that's not enough. Some people who find it annoying isn't enough to go and add a special flag for just that kind of thing that annoys you.

Comment: Now that the `homework` tag has been phased out on most sites, is-this-homework comments have become a lot rarer, so this request is moot.

Answer (score 10):

Although I believe that [inquiries about homework questions are necessary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130559/102937) I do like this idea.  Once the conversation has taken place, homework comments don't need to stay around.

Comment: I agree that once the determination has been made, one way or the other, the comments can be safely removed. But I don't think a special flag is needed for this. It's no different than any other comment that is no longer necessary.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I assume this would make a comment be deletable by a single flag, not be a new flag reason or type of flag, similar to how comments with the words "accept rate" are nuked with only 1 flag. I'm just saying this because your comment there has some upvotes, as if people aren't sure how this would most likely be implemented.

Comment: what happens if someone's name is "Foo Homework"? and I ping him like `@foo homework hello world?`

Comment: Is cleaning up "use the homework tag" and "is this homework‽"-type comments a significant part of your workload?

Comment: @Gilles: Not especially, no.