# Lower the flag barrier for "homework" comments

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags, homework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please add “homework” to the one-click comment flagging list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130568/please-add-homework-to-the-one-click-comment-flagging-list)

If the phrase *"accept rate"* (or similar<sup>1</sup>) is in a comment it takes [1 comment flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104359/should-your-accept-rate-only-be-known-to-you/104362#104362) to auto-delete the comment.

Now that [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) is [officially deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) can this functionality be extended to include comments that mention homework? For instance, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689965/student-average-mark-query-and-subqueries#comment17129116_12689965).

> Is this homework?

Maybe anything that matches `home\s?work` could require only one flag to remove it.

<sup>1. I can't find any official question/answer where this is stated.</sup>

Comment: Problem: [Please do your homework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) when asking a question, so we have enough information to provide an answer.

Comment: Now, that would a legit comment, and I don't think putting that in the risk of being auto-nuked would be desired.

Comment: It requires someone to flag the comment so there's no auto-nuking; in the same way that accept rate comments aren't automatically evil if they explain how it works for a first time user not all comments that have "homework" in them are evil.

Comment: Yes, but it would require only _one_ user flagging it. Maybe it would be better to require two flags.

Comment: Doesn't matter anymore, given that we're going to get rid of the homework tag and all the conditions that come with it.